# Document methods in a ruby c extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I've been working on some ruby libraries with C extensions now. And I want to give users access to the `irb#help` method, e.g:

```rb
> help("Array#empty?")
# Prints documentation for the method.
```

I've been using the same way to name functions as [ruby core](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5d04ac6ea2fefa4d6e4d22ab9c9903b8ff160167/array.c#L2878-L2889), and the same documentation pattern. However, irb always tell me that there is *Nothing known about FastPolyline.decode*.

Here's my method:

```c
/*
 * call-seq:
 *   FastPolylines.decode([[1,1]]) -> String
 *
 * Decodes a polyline.
 */
static VALUE
decode(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self) {
```

I've tried naming the method various ways, such as `rb_FastPolylines__decode`, `rb_fast_polylines_decode`, `rb_decode`. None worked..

I've been looking on internet, but couldn't find any convincing resource on *How to document a ruby C extension*. Do you have any inputs on this ?

Comment: Maybe this hay help? https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/52ebbd7b28d32aaa27b0d5f59e35804ebe7ed126/Rakefile#L35

Comment: Also, are you sure you are installing your library with `rdoc`? Can it be that you have `--no-rdoc` or `--no-document` in your .gemrc? If you add documentation to a pure ruby class or method in the gem, is it available in `help`?

Comment: @DNNX, thanks, this has changed a bit, now I have an empty documentation. Which is already much better ! However, It doesn't give the text I've added... About the second question, rdoc is on on my laptop :)